# Require client certificate only on one single page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, client-certificates

I have a website (MVC 4 ASP.NET) running on IIS that requires SLL (client certificates ignored).
There is just one page where I want to require the client certificate. In IIS I browsed to the specific page and changed the settings to Client Certificate Required.

This used to work in WebForms (changing the settings for the specific page), but this doesn't work and I think it's because of the MVC-routing.

I've seen 'tricks' with changing things in your web.config or even applicationHost.config, but is there no other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945921/enabling-ssl-client-certificate-required-for-specific-controller-or-action-in-as

Comment: Yes and no. It states there are no other options indeed (not on MVC level), so that's the worst answer possible. But I guess I have to take it, because of the lack of other answers.